# Natural Docs комментарии на нескольких языках

Tags: документация, multilanguage

Возможно ли комментировать проект на двух разных языках, чтобы потом сгенерировать две документации через naturaldocs?
Например в доксигенах для этого используется такой формат:

```
/**
* \~english @brief Sample method.
* \~polish @brief Przykladowa metoda.
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перерыв документацию, и немного поковыряв исходники выяснил ответ.
**Никак.**
Natural Docs не поддерживает возможность многоязычных комментариев. Как ни печально.